# Why doesn't SQLite support write to view?

Tags: sqlite, view

It seems like a curious omission, though from [the wording of their website](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) quite intentional.  Is there something about write to view that does not make sense for SQLite's purposes--perhaps since it's embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite allows editing views by creating triggers for views:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_trigger

Views are not editable by default, because it's hard to predict which columns of the view are really editable (relate to table column) and which not (they are constants, or expressions). For example you have view which does SELECT:

```
SELECT 'test', 456, substr(col, 2), col FROM table
```

In that case only last column make sense for editing.

Sometimes you do know that you could edit some expression, because the expression is convertable in both ways, for example:

```
SELECT hex(col) FROM table
```

For such column you can translate back the hexadecimal expression into binary value when user edited and entered a hex value.

This and many more cases are possible, so this has been left for the developer to implement proper edition algorithm to his best knowledge about the edited view column.